# Jekyll redirects are not generated at GitHub

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages

I'm using `jekyll-redirect-from` gem to generate redirect pages for my Jekyll website hosted with Github Pages. All works fine locally but no redirects HTMLs are generated on GitHub.

Here is my `_config.yml`

```
title: My Title
baseurl: /my-project
url: "https://my-organisarion.github.io/my-project"
google_analytics: # set tracking

permalinks: pretty
markdown: kramdown

exclude:
 - Gemfile
 - Gemfile.lock
```

Note, locally I'm setting `url: "http://localhost:4000"` and omiting `baseurl`.

and `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby RUBY_VERSION

gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-redirect-from"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your _config.yml:

```
gems:
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

Did you read this ? https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/

Comment: Thank a lot! That was it!